# Windows-7 Acer Aspire 5738 laptop simply turns off

Tags: windows-7, laptop, power-supply, battery, acer-aspire

My laptop simply switches off on its own...and I mean switch off without warning or anything...as if someone cut the power supply so the computer did not show any warning etc.

And this **happens only when the laptop is on Battery**. It never happens when it's on AC power.

And it's not a phenomenon which happens each time the laptop is on battery..it's only once a day or like that.

What's amazing is that there are no event logs of the time when it switches off. The only helpful event logged is "Even ID 6008: The previous system shutdown at 10:20:53 AM on ‎5/‎3/‎2016 was unexpected."

The computer runs all day long (almost 14 hours at a stretch) with light usage (Chrome browser and office applications). No game etc is installed.

And I can also confirm that the battery was sufficiently charged (76%) the last time this happened. When the laptop switches off, I can turn the computer back ON without connecting it to AC power and continue to use it on battery.

Any ideas in troubleshooting this?

EDIT: Umm...guys...this is misery...the laptop switched off even on AC power this time...now a solution is needed ASAP...please..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the power options in control panel to see how long your computer stay on while on battery (and your not working on the computer) before you check the battery, if it Turns off while your using it maybe the cause is different.

Comment: Hi. Were you referring to "Put the computer to sleep"?? It was 15 minutes for both "on battery" & "plugged in". I have changed it to "Never". Let's see how it goes. The last time the computer switched off was when it was on AC power and had been left unattended for 13 minutes whilst I went to grab a bite and had a download in progress.

Comment: Ok it might be the reason

Comment: If the response was convenient to your computer, kindly click on the green sign to settle the question

Comment: I know, Sam. I am always thank those who've helped me. I am just waiting to see if this is really working. I had set myself a target of 4 days to confirm whether it really worked for me...just to be on the safer side so if that it doesn't work, I don't have to unmark a reply as an answer and make someone feel bad. But then again, it's been 3 days without any problems so I guess it's working. Thank you!

Comment: BTW, any idea why the laptop trying to sleep would end up switching itself off instead of going to sleep? I ask this because in regular routine, I can safely put it to sleep through the start menu as well as the command prompt.

Comment: Maybe it was put to sleep for a long time so the battery was discharged or you have to check for more options like closing the Lid

Answer (score 1):

Since it only happens when running on the battery and you get absolutely no warning, the most likely explanation is that your battery does not charge well.  That causes it to appear fully charge even if it's not, so the system can not predict properly when it will run out of charge.

This is probably a problem with the battery itself that is due to be replaced, but could in rarer cases be due to a bad charger.

The only way to be 100% sure is to replace one or the other.  Since it's most likely a battery problem, trying a new battery would be a good idea.

Comment: Hi. When the system switches off like that, I can turn it back ON without connecting it to the AC power and continue to use it on battery itself. Had it been a problem of battery running out while showing that it still had the strength to go the distance, then should I be able to start the system on battery? (I think I must add this information to the original post.)

Comment: You should, but I still consider that the most likely explanation is a faulty battery.